# aws ec2 create-volume not creating volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm running the following command:

```
aws ec2 create-volume --region eu-west-1 --availability-zone eu-west-1a --snapshot-id snap-02583b4b1fb1d2d84
```

And I get the response:

```
{
    "SnapshotId": "snap-02583b4b1fb1d2d84",
    "Size": 40,
    "VolumeType": "standard",
    "Encrypted": true,
    "State": "creating",
    "VolumeId": "vol-0d7bec77ac1164266",
    "CreateTime": "2017-05-09T10:17:03.521Z",
    "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1a"
}
```

However, any subsequent command; such as:

```
aws ec2 wait volume-available --volume-ids vol-0d7bec77ac1164266
```

Returns:

```
Waiter VolumeAvailable failed: The volume 'vol-0d7bec77ac1164266' does not exist.
```

When I look on the web UI volumes dashboard; I cannot see the volume. I have checked in every region.

Anyone ever seen this behaviour before?

**UPDATE**

The command appears to work as expected if I execute it on another computer using a different IAM user with * permissions on * resources.

**UPDATE 2**

It appears that the volume is encrypted and the permissions may not be compensating for an encrypted volume.

Comment: If it's working on one computer and not another, make sure you have the latest version of the CLI installed. If you are on Linux, do `pip install awscli --upgrade`.

Comment: Yeah did that. It turned out to be a permissions issue. See my answer below. I believe there is a minor bug in the CLI whereby it should have reported a lack of permissions as opposed to report a successful create.

Comment: If that is the case, why does it work on a different computer? Did it have IAM different credentials?

Comment: Yes. The other computer had * permissions on * resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I have got it working; but I still believe that there is an issue with the CLI.

The volume being created is encrypted. Therefore permissions are needed to handle encrypted volumes.

The only way I could get it to work was to add the following permissions:

```
"kms:CreateGrant",
"kms:ListGrants",
"kms:RevokeGrant",
"kms:Encrypt",
"kms:Decrypt",
"kms:ReEncrypt*",
"kms:GenerateDataKey*",
"kms:DescribeKey",
"ec2:AttachVolume",
"ec2:DescribeVolume*",
"ec2:Describe*",
"ec2:CreateVolume",
"ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
"ec2:AttachVolume"
```

The tool doesn't report any permission errors when executing the command on an encrypted volume.

I've raised the issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2592

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue attempting to create a Volume from an encrypted Snapshot. The create volume command appears to complete successfully:

```
{
  "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-1a", 
  "Encrypted": true, 
  "VolumeType": "gp2", 
  "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxx", 
  "State": "creating", 
  "Iops": 100, 
  "SnapshotId": "snap-xxxxx", 
  "CreateTime": "2017-07-14T21:03:24.430Z", 
  "Size": 10
}
```

However, the Volume never appears to be created and cannot be found attempting to describe it.

The issue was that the KMS key the Snapshot was created with was pending deletion. By cancelling the KMS deletion and re-enabling the key the Volume was created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce your problem.

I did the following steps:

Created an IAM user with these permissions as an inline policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Created a volume from a snapshot (as that User):

```
aws ec2 create-volume --region ap-southeast-2 --availability-zone ap-southeast-2a --snapshot-id snap-abcd1234 --profile xyz

{
    "AvailabilityZone": "ap-southeast-2a", 
    "Encrypted": false, 
    "VolumeType": "standard", 
    "VolumeId": "vol-03e2eee8e64f593d3", 
    "State": "creating", 
    "SnapshotId": "snap-abcd1234", 
    "CreateTime": "2017-05-11T05:17:23.960Z", 
    "Size": 30
}
```

The volume was created successfully.

That user doesn't have permissions to call `VolumeAvailable`, so I used a different user:

```
aws ec2 wait volume-available --volume-ids vol-03e2eee8e64f593d3 --region ap-southeast-2 --profile normal
```

The command completed immediately without error.

Comment: What permissions did the user have?

Comment: The permissions are shown at the beginning of my Answer. They only had `ec2:CreateVolume` on `*`. If you are asking about the user who called `VolumeAvailable`, they had Admin permissions. The main point is that only `CreateVolume` is required to create the EBS Volume. Maybe you ran `volume-available` against the wrong region?

Comment: Nope. Like I said. I checked every region. Even on the web UI. It definitely did not create it. But when I gave it * permissions, it worked.